# E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "Book::Book"

Tags: c++, объекты

Можете помочь?Я написал этот код в vs 2015 и все нормально работало. Как только скопировал код в мы 2017 дает ошибку "E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "Book::Book", соответствующие списку аргументов","MVBook::MVBook", соответствующие списку аргументов" , E1790 на конструктор по умолчанию для "Library" нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена
Вот мой код

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Book
{

protected:
    char *title;
public:
    Book(char *t);

    Book &operator =(Book &t)
    {

    }
    ~Book()
    {
        delete[] title;
    }
};

class MVBook : public Book
{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &t, MVBook &x);
    friend Library;
    int counter;
public:
    MVBook(char *t, int i) : Book(t)
    {
        counter = i;
    }

    void print(ostream &t)
    {
        t << title << endl;
        t << counter << endl;
    }

    ~MVBook()
    {
        delete[] title;
    }

};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &t, MVBook &x)
{
    x.print(t);
    return t;
}

class Library
{
    Book books[10];
    int i = 0;
public:
    void add(Book &t)
    {
        books[i] = t;
        i++;
    }
};


Book::Book(char *t)
{
    title = new char[strlen(t + 1)];
    strcpy(title, t);
}

int main()
{

    Book A("Alice in the wonderland");
    Book B("Basic of C++");
    MVBook D("Dictionary", 5);
    Library C;
    C.add(A);
    C.add(B);
    cout << D;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Этот код никак не мог компилироваться в VS2015 уже из-за бессмысленного `friend Library;`. Именно такую же ошибку вы получите и в VS2017 тоже.

Comment: Я этот friend Library; в vs 2017 написал. Но все же без этого все работало в vs 2015. Т.к у нас в универе только vs 2015.

Comment: Во-первых, что значит "я написал"? Тут никому не интересно гадать, что и когда вы написали, дописали или переписали. Приводите реальный код. Во-вторых, нет, вы что-то выдумываете. Даже без `friend Library;` в VS2015 такой код НЕ компилируется по той же причине, что и в VS2017 - отсутствует конструктор по умолчанию для `Library`. А что там у вас творится "в универе" нам отсюда не видно.

Answer (score 0):

В классе **Book** у вас есть только конструктор от строки. А по стандарту конструктор по умолчанию не создаётся если у вас уже есть другой конструктор.

В классе **Library** books записаны в массив. А для массива *обязательно* чтобы элемент имел конструктор по умолчанию.

Да напишите вы в Book этот конструктор , и ✝ с ним.

```
  char *title { nullptr } ;
public:
  Book ( ) { }
```

Comment: Я добавил, но ошибка E0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "Book::Book осталась